# How toggle element visibility with chrome extension on browserAction click event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to make Chrome extension which loads in iframe instead of popup. After user clicks extension icon, the extension creates iframe with popup.html in it. After user click extension's icon again the iframe vanishes.

And this behaviour need to work on every tab.

But action gets repeated as many times as many times user switch between tabs and he/she clicks extension icon.

**How can I achieve proper flow?**

1. User click extension icon -> show extension popup in iframe
2. User click extension icon again -> hide extension popup
3. User switch to another tab and click extension icon -> show extension popup in iframe
   ... and so on

This is my code:

**background.**

```js
function togglePlugin (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
    file: 'scripts/inject.js'
  })
};

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(togglePlugin)
```

**inject.js**

```js
function toggleVisisbility (node) {
  console.log(node.style.display)
  node.style.display = (node.style.display === 'none' || node.style.display === '') ? 'block' : 'none'
}

function appendIframe(app) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  // Must be declared at web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
  iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html')

  // Some styles for a fancy sidebar
  iframe.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:0;right:0;display:block;' +
                         'width:380px;height:575px;z-index:99999999;' +
                         'border: none;' + 
                         'box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);'
  app.appendChild(iframe)
}

function insertIframe(anchor) {
  let app = Array.from(anchor.childNodes).find(function(node){ return node.id === 'popup-app'})

  if (app) {
    if (app.querySelectorAll('iframe').length === 0) {
      // app.innerHTML = ''
      appendIframe(app)
    }
    toggleVisisbility(app)
  }
}

var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id
if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
  var anchor = document.getElementById('app-anchor')
  console.log(anchor)
  if (anchor) {
    insertIframe(anchor)
  } else {
    const AppRoot = document.createElement('div', { id: 'app-anchor' });
    AppRoot.id = 'app-anchor';
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(AppRoot);

    AppRoot.innerHTML = '<div style="display: none" id="popup-app"></div>';
    insertIframe(AppRoot)
  }
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const AppRoot = document.createElement('div', { id: 'app-anchor' });
  AppRoot.id = 'app-anchor';
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.appendChild(AppRoot);

  AppRoot.innerHTML = '<div style="display: none" id="popup-app"></div>';
});
```

**manifest.json**

```js
{
  ...
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/chromereload.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "management",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "background",
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/contentscript.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "24": "images/icon24.png",
      "32": "images/icon32.png"
    },
    "default_title": "__MSG_appName__"
    // "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "popup.html",
    "scripts/inject.js"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Your inject.js executes each time you click on browserAction. I think you should use messaging to hide/show your iFrame.

Comment: I tryed to use runtime messages but nothing changes
`chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {method: "togglePopup"}, function(response) {});`   and in contentscript.js `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) { alert('Message from View:\n'+ JSON.stringify(msg)); });`

Comment: If alert message is displaying that means the message is properly passed to CS. No you can do it very easily. Think like it is a normal html+js page and acheive what you want to do.

Comment: Yes I getting messages but I can't understand why it gets many times as I described in the question above

Comment: Use this to send message: `chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                method : "togglePopup"
            }); 
        });`

Comment: I have found the problem ( I guess :) ) I have in my popup.html `<script src="scripts/background.js"></script>` and this is was the reason why event fires many times